# is it possible to send message to specific user on facebook messenger in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-messenger

i've to implement the scenario described below

for example

> app allows users to login through facebook in app. now in app  i want
>   to select any register user(from all users) and send message directly
>   from app to that specific person in facebook messenger automatically.
>   without going into messenger app

**is it possible in android or not ?**

if it is possible then **please guide me how can i implement this. ?**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a specific message that is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy and privacy. But you can pass uri to the intent like `Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/user_id");`